# DatePipe in Angular to return only MM/yy

Tags: javascript, angular

I got confused with Angular.
I need an input text that will only accept "MM/yy" (expiration date) same in this picture

[image]

But when I use this code, it displays a calendar and not automatically formats the text. (and it accepts dd/mm/yyyy)

This is what I used:

```
<input type="date" value="expirationDate | date:'MM/yy'"/>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You are only transforming data with the pipe, when you need to make a custom form control, something like this https://material.angular.io/guide/creating-a-custom-form-field-control